# Why am I getting the "Argument 2 passed to drupal_array_set_nested_value() must be of the type array, null given" error?

Tags: nodes, search

The Drupal "Search" module is not working when accessed from the /search/node page.

When I use the search functionnality from a Search block, it redirects me to the /search/node/mySearchKey (I entered mySearchKey in the block) and displays the results correctly.

But when I use the search functionnality from the "Search form" it redirect me to /search/node/ and an error appears. "Error : the website encountered an unexpected error. Try again later". The request POST show a HTML 500 response.

The error report shows this:

> Recoverable fatal error : Argument 2 passed to
>   drupal_array_set_nested_value() must be of the type array, null given,
>   called in \includes\form.inc on line 2657 and defined dans
>   drupal_array_set_nested_value() (ligne 6703 dans
>   \includes\common.inc).

The code causing the error is drupal_array_set_nested_value($form_state['values'], $element['#parents'], $value, TRUE);`.

I checked the values of `$value`.  I have an array with 17 entries.

```
string 'node' (length=4)
string 'form-xxxxxxxx' (length=48)
string 'xxxxxx' (length=43)
string 'search_form' (length=11)
string 'mySearchKey ' (length=7)
```

The last entry of the array is `string 'mySearchKey' (length=7)`
We can see that mySearchKey appears 2 times in this array.

I have also checked `$element['#parents']`. I have an array with 17 entries.

```
string 'module' (length=6)
string 'form_build_id' (length=13)
string 'form_token' (length=10)
string 'form_id' (length=7)
string 'keys' (length=4)
```

We can see that the values matches the values array, but the last item of `$element['#parents']` is `null`, when it is supposed to match my duplicate `mySearchKey` entry.

I think the null value from my error comes from here.
I have no idea how it get there.

Someone has an idea of how to fix it ?